# Make element take full height of flex item container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is this a bug or what?

```css
.page__header {
  background: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.page__header h1 {
  flex: 1 0;
}

.page__header button {
   order: 5;
}

.page__header div {
  align-self: left;
  order: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.page__header div input {
  min-width: 260px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class='page__header'>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <div>
    <input>
  </div>
  <button>some button</button>
</div>
```

Chrome, as always, refuses to cooperate. 
Does anyone know how to force an **input** to take the **full heigh**t of its *flex* item container?

On Firefox it obeys the `100%` height.

Comment: Seems like anything doesn't get height in percentages in Chrome when inside a Flex item.. again, Chrome suck.

Comment: How was this a duplicate of a same question asked *after* this one? just because it randomly got more popular? ridicules, it should have been marked as a duplicate itself back when it was asked :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to force an input to take the full height of its flex item container?

Here are three options:

#### Option #1

Make the `input` a flex item by removing its `div` parent.

```
<div class='page__header'>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <input>
    <button>some button</button>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2mvtrscq/)

NOTES:

- When wrapped by the `div`, the `input` is not a flex item. It's a child of a flex item, so it ignores flex properties.
- In a flex container, the [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-items) are the in-flow child elements only. Descendants beyond the children are not flex items and ignore flex properties.
- Once `input` is a child of the `.page__header` flex container, default flex properties (like `align-items: stretch`) apply.

---

#### Option #2

Make the `div` wrapping the `input` a flex container, converting `input` into a flex item.

HTML back to original:

```
<div class='page__header'>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div>
        <input>
    </div>
    <button>some button</button>
</div>
```

CSS adjustments:

```
.page__header div {
    /* align-self: left; */
    order: 2;
    position: relative;
    display: flex; /* NEW */
}

.page__header div input {
    min-width: 260px;
    padding: 0 1em;
    /* height: 100%; REMOVE */
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2mvtrscq/24)

NOTES:

- With the `div` flex item doubling as a (nested) flex container, default flex properties (like `align-items: stretch`) will apply to `input`.
- `height: 100%` is removed because it would otherwise override the flex `align-*` properties.

---

#### Option #3

Using percentage heights.

The reason that `height: 100%` wasn't working for you is because you weren't specifying heights for all parent elements, as [required by the spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276) when using percentage heights. (The fact that it works in Firefox suggest that Chrome adheres more closely to the spec.)

If you're going to use percentage heights, and the element is not absolutely positioned, then you need to specify the height for each parent element up to and including `body` and the root element (`html`).

Add this to your CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
.page__header { height: 30%; }
.page__header div { height: 100%; }
.page__header div input {  height: 100%; }
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2mvtrscq/2/)

NOTES:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: Indeed, setting the flex item to also have `display:flex` and removing the `height` property from the input solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try taking it out-of-flow:

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```css
.page__header {
  background: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.page__header h1 {
  flex: 1 0;
}
.page__header div {
  align-self: left;
  order: 4;
  position: relative;
}
.page__header div input {
  min-width: 260px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='page__header'>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <div>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

This may break your layout, though.

Comment: I can't, it's a part of a dynamic structure, I have no idea in what order it will be positioned as a flex item. I wonder if there's an open bug on this..

Comment: Bro, your editing my question wasn't cool, now it's not using SASS, and it's not as easy to debug using inspector. inline-code in stackoverflow isn't better than jsbin sometimes .

Comment: @vsync Note StackOverflow requires including the code in the question itself. I thought a runnable snippet would be nice, but feel free to remove the snippet, include the SASS code, and a link to jsbin if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your time in trying to answering this question friend! I appreciate it.